# Add colored String with italic font style to Tool Tip Text

Tags: java, html, swing, tooltip, jcomponent

How to add colored String with italic font style to Tool Tip Text?

Actually I have overridden the `getToolTipText(MouseEvent e)` method from `JComponent`  in Core java and added some tooltiptext `Strings` in to it, now i want to add one more `String` to it with `Italic font and Red color` . Can you please tell me how to add colored string to ToolTipText in Java, I tried using HTML but i did not get the result.

```
String message=  "<html><p style='font-style:italic;color:red;'> Minor </p> </html> ";
```

I tried above `HTML` for the 'Minor' string to add that in to ToolTipText but it displaying all the *HTML content* in the ToolTipText.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4):

> ..overridden the `getToolTipText(Mouseevent e)`

Why not just *set* the tool tip text?  A strategy which seems to work just fine here.  E.G.

[image: Styled ToolTip]

```
import javax.swing.*;

class StyledToolTip {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                String s=  "<html><p style='font-style:italic;color:red;'>" + 
                        "Minor</p></html> ";
                JLabel lbl = new JLabel(s);
                lbl.setToolTipText(s);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, lbl);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, yeah i know that what you said in above but my case is i have a Sring content(Data) and i want to  concatenate the above HTML String ("MINOR")  with that and the Total String  i need to add in to a StringBuffer. Please say how to do it. i tried to concatenate the above HTML to the Existing String and appended to StringBuffer but i am getting the total HTML instead of "MINOR" with red and italic font.

Comment: Like I said 4 hours ago.  *For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).*